# Automator opening on startup when it shouldn't

Tags: automator, startup

I built an application in Automator and triggered it to run on startup. It does so successfully, but the Automator interface also opens on startup.

I've checked the hide mark, but it's not doing anything. I read online that sometimes software itself overrides the login items, but I can't find anywhere within Automator to hideself.

Does Automator always have to open the interface when it runs a workflow?  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files saved as Workflows in Automator, run in the Automator app. That is why Automator launches when you open your killpulsesecure.workflow. Save your killpulsesecure workflow in Automator as an application and add that to your Login Items instead.

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly, didn't know I could create an application